# Python 3 - Nested for loops with .count() to check string count per character in word

Tags: python, anagram

Here I'm asking for a word, and generating a list of all combinations for the letters in `word` variable, in theory (in my head) the for loop's `if` statement *should* work.

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

word = input("Enter a word, preferably short")


PossibleWithWordLetters = [''.join(i) for i in product(word, repeat = len(word))]

for a in PossibleWithWordLetters:
    if word.count(word[i]) [for i in range(len(word))] == 1 and a in PossibleWithWordLetters:
        print(a)
```

The aim of the program is to list all valid anagrams from a word inputted - and checked where it only contains one of each of the letters in `word` - then i'll check this against a word file of real words - which I haven't got round to yet.

Any help is appreciated on getting the `for` loop to work.

Comment: Don't generate all permutations of the word if you are going to match it against a dictionary. There are much less words in any dictionary than permutations of a 11-12 letter word. Instead, go through you rictionary and check if any word is an anagram of yours

Comment: I am unable to understand the title (what is this "with to"?).  Can you fix it?

Comment: @adl - yes sorry - missed out a word.

Comment: @hege_hegedus ok that's a good way to think about it, I will try this later today.

Comment: Think more about what data you actually _need_, and how you would store and retrieve it.  If you're allowed to use the standard library, look at the things [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can do.  If that's not allowed, you can do the same things with a dictionary and judicious use of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I didn't quite understood your question, but it looks like you are trying to generate anagrams of a word, which are *permutations* of *characters*.
There is no need to count the letters, as python can generate the permutations directly:

```
from itertools import permutations
from string import ascii_lowercase

word = input("Enter a word, preferably short: ")

PossibleWithWordLetters = [''.join(i) for i in permutations(word)]

for a in PossibleWithWordLetters:
    print(a)
```

If you want to check if two worstrings are anagrams of each other, here are some examples:

```
# using string.count
def check_anagram1(a, b):
    return all(a.count(c) == b.count(c) for c in set(a) | set(b))

# using collections.Counter
from collections import Counter
def check_anagram2(a, b):
    return Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

Comment: yeah - sorry I didn't make it very clear - creating the permutations is ok - that looks like a simpler way to do the same thing, it's just then checking to see if `word` letters can be reordered to make another or any word in `PossibleWithWordLetters` - which is what I tried to do with the `for` loop.

Comment: @RPiPasswordGen With permutations you don't need that check. But just in case, I updated the answer, so you have functions to check if two strings are anagrams